# Conditional formatting when max work hours is reached based on a formulated cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

- Is it possible to do a conditional formatting on column M (Total worked hours) when total work hours >40 hours per work week (Monday-Sunday) based on the employee's position REGULAR EMPLOYEE (cell G7, this is a drop down list e.g. (a)Regular Employee and (b)Manager)?
- I would need the work week (Monday-Sunday) total hours in column M to be in red fill if it is >40 for Regular Employees.
- If so, can someone please help on the formula?
- Please note:

  - A13 formula: =IF(ISNA(MATCH(WEEKDAY(B13,2),Dunday,0)),"","NW")
  - B13 formula: =G9
  - B14 formula: =IF(B13="","",IF(B13+1>$G$10,"",B13+1))
  - G7 is a drop-down menu: (a) Regular Employee, (b) Manager
- Please find attached picture for reference.
- Thank you.
  [image: Timesheet]

Comment: What have you tried?  This seems straight forward to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you add a helper column then hide it, and set the Number format for cells of column M?
If yes, such as column N, please enter the formula `=SUM(INDIRECT("M"&ROW(B13)-WEEKDAY(B13,2)+1):INDIRECT("M"&ROW(B13)-WEEKDAY(B13,2)+7))` in N13, to get the hours each week.

[image]

Then chose the cells of M column, enter the formula below for conditional formatting.
`=AND($G$7="Regular Employee",N13>40)`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Emily, that worked perfectly!!! :-)